# Object init attributes not accessible in downstream classes

Tags: python, class

I'm having issues with accessing object attributes when those objects are passed into new classes.

example:

```
    class foo:
        def __init__(self, x):
            self.x = x

    class bar: 
        def __init__(self, foo: foo, y):
            self.foo = foo, 
            self.y = y

    class why: 
        def __init__(self, bar: bar, z):
            self.bar = bar
            self.z = z

    a = foo(1)
    b = bar(a, 2)
    c = why(b, 3)
```

When I try to access `b.foo.x` i get an `AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'x'`

but when I try to access `c.bar.y` I successfully have `2` returned. Why can I access the `y` attribute of the `bar`class from the `why` class, but I can't access the `x` attribute of the `foo` class from the `bar` class?

I have a series of custom objects that are being passed into custom classes - what is the appropriate way to accomplish this?

There is also a weird case where when I run `<parent_object>.<child_object>.__dict__.keys()` I see all of the methods of the `<child_object>`, but not of the attributes assigned during the `__init__` phase.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You have a simple typo — the comment at the end of `self.foo = foo,` makes `self.foo` a tuple. Remove the comma, and it will work.